# Implementing the Numerov method for solving ODEs with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'd like to implement the [Numerov scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov%27s_method) for solving an ODE (Scroedinger Eq time-independent) with `NDSolve`. I tried in analogy with the Runge Kutta example in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html#1701730745):

```
Numerovv[]["Step"[rhs_, h_, t_, x_]] := Module[{},
  -x[t - h] (2 (12 + 5 h^2 rhs[t - h]) )/(-12 + h^2 rhs[t]) + 
   x[t - 2 h] (12 - h^2 rhs[t - 2 h]) /(-12 + h^2 rhs[t])
  ];
Numerovv[___]["StepInput"] = {"F"["T"], "H", "T", "X"};
Numerovv[___]["StepOutput"] = "X";
Numerovv[___]["StepMode"] := Fixed;
Numerovv[___]["DifferenceOrder"] := 4;
```

But when I select `Method -> "Numerovv"`, I get

> The value of the option Method -> Numerovv is not a known built-in method, a symbol that could be a user-defined method, or a list with a name followed by method options. >>

Do I miss something?

Comment: This is not the error I get when I use your code.  I get an error about the step function not returning an acceptable form.  [This](http://pastebin.com/raw/ivrnZF9H) is the code I use, and the error message I get is ""The Step function for Method -> Numerovv returned {-1.\ \
{1.,0.}[-0.0472329]+2.\ {1.,0.}[-0.0236164],-1.\ \
{1.,0.}[-0.0472329]+1.99944\ {1.,0.}[-0.0236164]}, which is not an \
acceptable form.""

Comment: In your specification of "StepInput", you define the function to take one variable, which matches the step function, but you don't define "X" to be a variable with an argument.  That is one issue, but fixing it doesn't solve the problem.  The documentation on user-defined NDSolve methods is scarce.  If someone can find more info than that linked in the question I'd be interested to read it.

Comment: The problem is that the built-in method framework is setup for $\mathbf y^\prime=\mathbf f(x,\mathbf y)$, while Numerov is a method specialized for *second order conservative* equations, $y^{\prime\prime}=f(x,y)$. An "adapter" would be needed, but I'm drawing a blank on how to write one.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://www.physics.wisc.edu/~tgwalker/448-9Mathematica/448%20Mathematica/MatrixNumerov.pdf and http://k2.chem.uh.edu/quantum/Supplement/Numerov/

Comment: @jset Have you solved the "not an acceptable form" problem?If you do,PLEASE post it.Many thanks.

Comment: @J.M.  I noticed that Adams method,which is a multistep method,can also be implanted manually into `NDSolve`.The example is listed along with the `Classical RungeKutta` example mentioned [above](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html#51030643).Is it possible to solve this Numerov problem using the same way?

Comment: As I said, the sticking point is not that the method is single- or multistep; it's that `NDSolve[]`'s framework assumes that methods plugged into it are for $\mathbf y^\prime=\mathbf f(x, \mathbf y)$. Numerov is not a method in that format, so adaptation is necessary. That you might need to figure out.